# How can I join a machine to a domain with duplicate short-names in the same forest?

Tags: active-directory, domain, kerberos

I have 4 Domains, 1 Forest Root, 3 children.  The children are nearly replicas, and have their machines named the same in all 3 child domains.

For Example:

```
DC1.dev.example.com
DC2.dev.example.com
DC1.test.example.com
DC2.test.example.com
DC1.prod.example.com
DC2.prod.example.com
```

From what I can tell, the only issue is the SPN duplication on domain join that requires manually fixing.

```
DC1.dev.example.com
HOST/DC1
HOST/DC1.dev.example.com
```

The shortname is a duplicate, so when I add test, the SPNSET function of the AD Domain join process fails, if I manually enter the fqdn in the computer name (extended attributes, service principle names) all is well.

**Can I prevent the shortname from being added to SPN?**

Answer (score 0):

**"Can I prevent the shortname from being added to SPN?"**

No.

But you can automate it with a script to add the machines to the domain, including following up with the manual changes. That way you can automated the whole process.

These links should help with that.

http://powershellblogger.com/2015/10/join-computer-to-domain-with-desired-computer-name-and-ou/

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee617263.aspx

Comment: we already automate domain join processes,  and a post setup script could be done,  however this is not an answer.

Comment: Also this will not work for MSSQL Listeners, which also add shortnames

Comment: Sorry, you are right - I didn't actually answer your question! "Can I prevent the shortname from being added to SPN?" The answer is "no". Although please realise that I am trying to help! You didn't mention sql listeners. Maybe this can help - there are more reputable sources, but they don't go into enough detail.
https://jeromequief.wordpress.com/2014/05/12/sql-2012-ha-groups-unattended/